# How do I use the qml profiler in qt 5.3.0?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qml, profiler

I cannot seem to start the built-in profiler, I have tried a number of settings and it still wont run. I get this message;

[image]

I have enabled qml debugging under 'Build Steps' like so;

[image]

I have also enabled it under 'Debugger Settings' (and followed the pre-requisites).

[image]

I have restarted, rebuilt, cleaned and re-ran qmake. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check Projects->(Whatever target)->**Run settings** and make sure the QML checkbox is set next to the debugger languages. Report back if this fixes your problem.

Comment: I have tried this as can be seen from the third screenshot, thanks anyway.